# Creating search box in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula

I am creating a search box on google sheet using =FILTER function. But my problem is it can only return the value in 1 column which is COL B. I want to know if it can return the data from column A as well? I tried to tweak the forumla but i am only getting errors.

Here's the formula that I created.

=filter(data!A2:B, SEARCH(D2,data!B2:B))

Any inputs will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It is difficult (or impossible) to understand what you are trying to do in the absence of seeing the spreadsheet, layout, data, data types, etc., and knowing your full end goal. Consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a sample spreadsheet containing enough realistic "dummy" data in the correct locations to illustrate the goal). And then explain *fully* that end goal (e.g., list all columns you will want to match for, etc., not just A and/or B unless those are the only ones).

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for checking this thread. Using the formula above, I can only pull out the data from column B. I want to do a dynamic search bar on where it can pull out the data from column A as well? Kindly check this link below. I appreciate your time https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hqbDLoxTXXPTcYYNMOWXRIG4PlxNCrjVeV5Sy-DdS_M/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've duplicated your "Search" sheet (renamed "Erik Help"). The formula there:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(data!A2:B, SEARCH(B2,data!A2:A&"|"&data!B2:B)))`

All I did was concatenate the two columns you want to search, forming one string. I interposed a pipe symbol to eliminate data bleed. (The pipe symbol could have been any symbol that is unlikely to turn up in your actual data.)

Comment: Thanks man! This is what I've been looking. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Great. If you would, please take a moment to mark my post with the working solution as "Best Answer" by clicking the checkmark you should see beside it. This let's the contributor community at large know that the issue has been fully resolved, and it allows future site visitors to more quickly find answers that relate to their own similar issues.